# Finding sum of integral values of '$a$'

Tags: roots, quadratics, integers

**Question:** Find the sum of all integral values of  '$a$' such that $$a(x^2+x-1) \leq(x^2+x+1)^2 \text { for all } x \in R$$

**My attempt:**

I thought about representing $$a\leq \frac{(x^2+x+1)^2}{(x^2+x-1)}$$

but as $x\rightarrow \infty$, This goes to $\infty$ also. I don't really know the approach further. Please help out. I considered quadratic equations for a while but no fruitful result.

Comment: Reworking the final inequality a bit yields $a\le x^2+x+3+{4\over x^2+x-1}$.  What is the minimum value this inequality takes on in the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write your inequality as $$a(x^2+x+1-2)\le (x^2+x+1)^2$$ and set $$t=x^2+x+1$$
then you have to solve $$a(t-2)\le t^2$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Got my answer. Thanks

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh What was your answer?

Comment: @aras  I got $a \in [-9/20 , 8]$ Thus sum was 36

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh Great, thanks. I got that too.